# Implementing View.OnClickListener not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a firebase authentication and my class implements `View.OnClickListener` but when clicking on views nothing happens, any help?

Here's my code

```
    private void updateUI(int i) {
        if(i == R.id.tv_not_member){
            mLoginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mNotMemberTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mUsernameField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRegisterButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mNotMemberTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else if (i == R.id.tv_member){
            mUsernameField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mRegisterButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mNotMemberTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mLoginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mNotMemberTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.btn_email_create_account) {
            createAccount(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
        } else if (i == R.id.btn_email_sign_in) {
            signIn(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
        } else if(i == R.id.tv_not_member){
            updateUI(i);
        } else if (i == R.id.tv_member){
            updateUI(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the `OnClickListener`?

Comment: sorry for this silly question, I actually forgot to set it on my views. thank yous so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify onClickListener for your views.

For example:

> textView.setOnClickListener(this);

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView TextView;
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialiseViews();
    initialiseListeners();
}

public void initialiseViews() {
    textView = (textView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

}

public void initialiseListeners() {
    textView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.text_view:

                    // do here

        break;

    }

}
}
```